# Unhandled error while playing audio Discord.js and @discordjs/voice

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to rewrite my personal music bot with the new implementation of audio management in Discord.js V13 with @discordjs/voice.
The bot actually plays music fine, but at like 3/4 of the song, it crashes, and throws an "unhandled error". But I don't know where this error is, and where should I handle it. Please help! 
The error:

```
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

AudioPlayerError: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at node:net:687:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)
Emitted 'error' event on AudioPlayer instance at:
    at OggDemuxer.onStreamError (file:///C:/Users/Saverio/Desktop/wltst/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.mjs:912:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at OggDemuxer.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

(The full error is extremely long.) 
My code:

```
import {
  createAudioPlayer,
  joinVoiceChannel,
  createAudioResource,
} from "@discordjs/voice";
import { MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";
import Command from "../components/Command.js";
import ytdl from "ytdl-core";
import yts from "yt-search";

const queue = new Map();

export default new Command({
  name: "play",
  description: "Get some tunes!",
  execute: async (message, args) => {
    await message.channel.sendTyping();
    const vc = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!vc) {
      return message.reply(
        "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!"
      );
    }

    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: vc.id,
      guildId: vc.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: vc.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
      selfDeaf: false,
    }).subscribe(player);

    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    let track = {};

    if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
      const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
      track = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        duration: songInfo.timestamp,
        thumbnail: songInfo.videoDetails.thumbnail,
        views: songInfo.videoDetails.viewCount,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
      };
    } else {
      const search = await yts(args.join(" "));

      if (search) {
        track = {
          title: search.videos[0].title,
          duration: search.videos[0].duration,
          thumbnail: search.videos[0].thumbnail,
          views: search.videos[0].views,
          url: search.videos[0].url,
        };
      }
    }
    const stream = ytdl(track.url, { filter: "audioonly" });
    const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`**\`${track.title}\`**`)
      .setDescription(
        `**Duration: \`${track.duration}\`
      Views: \`${track.views}\`**`
      )

    message.channel.send({
      embeds: [embed],
    });
    player.play(resource);
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ytdl, however I am aware there were some issues with it when it came to streaming audio with discord.js. Have you tried using another package like play-dl?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is with `ytdl-core`, `ytdl-core` doesn't work properly in node ver 16**

You should use [youtube-dl-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl-exec) (It requires python, so you have to install python too)

[Source / more information: ytdl stop stream after few minute](https://lightrun.com/answers/fent-node-ytdl-core-ytdl-stop-stream-after-few-minute).